# Programmatic Autolayout changes inside UITableViewCell updated only after orientation change

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` with automatic row heights and a custom `UITableViewCell`. Inside the `UITableViewCell`, I first add some `UIButton`s with programmatic Autolayout constraints. They are positioned perfectly as I want. Then, after 3 seconds (`NSTimer`), I remove all those `UIButton`s and re-add a different number of them again. (For e.g initially I have 4 `UIButtons`, after 3 seconds, I remove those 4 `UIButton`s and add 3 different ones.

**Initially**:

[image: Initially]
**After 3 seconds**:

[image: 3 seconds later]

**Post rotate:**

[image]

Why is this happening? I don't see any Autolayout warnings. Also, after an orientation change, everything is correctly positioned. What is it that requires an orientation change? How can I force this manually?(reloading the tableview just for this seems too much to do)

PS: I tried using `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`, `layoutIfNeeded`, `layoutSubviews` but to no avail.

Here's the `UITableViewCell` code: http://pastebin.com/TcHUXgDU. (Added a pastebin to not pollute this space) But basically, there's a `configure:` method that I have inside my tableview subclass which I call in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of its containing `UITableView`. This method adds those constraints. Also, after the timer fires, the same code is called (in another function) except that the number of items I add are different from the initial number of items.

This is my `UITableViewCell` layout: (Only top,bottom,leading,trailing constraints have been added to the UIView "Outerview")

[image: uitableviewcell layout]

Comment: can you post some code? and prior the orientation i can see the height of the cell is varying, which is making the buttons squeeze to the padding, whereas the orientation change makes it ok by changing the height of the cell.

Comment: I've posted some code. Also, prior to the orientation, the cell height is constant for all 3 cells. (unlike varying like you say)

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but you'll have a much nicer time implementing autolayout programmatically if you use a library like [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry)

Answer (score 0):

You need reload the UITableView, this will re-caculate the height of the cell

Comment: Yes that's like a panacea with uitableviewcell layout heights, but I was wondering if there's a cheaper way to just force updates in the uitableviewcell layout.

Comment: - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> * _Nonnull)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation.  check UITableView's doc

Comment: Ended up reloading the tableview after all